# How can i use sql count in these multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am still a php/mysql newbie and I am working on mysql table relationship concept and i am having an issue with using mysql count in multiple table. Here is my db structure.

```
**product table**
id    product_name  product_img      groupeid
1     Sneaker Mark  sneaker_adi.png     1
2     bag Eric      bageric.png         2
3     Sneaker Etoi  sneakeretoi.jpg     1

**groupe table**
group_id  group_name
 1         men
 2         women

**category table**
catid   catname
 1      sneaker-shoes
 2      bag-woman

**productcategory table**
  prod_id    cat_ID
   1           1
   2           2
   3           1
```

What i want to do is to determine the number of sneaker-shoes using mysql.

We can see that the number of sneaker-shoes in the db is 2.

But how can i use `**count()**` in these multiple tables.

I tried like this;

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) product.id,product_name,catname FROM product INNER JOIN productcategory ON product.id = prod_id INNER JOIN category ON catid = cat_ID WHERE catname='sneaker-shoes'";
```

i got error like:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\kbashopping\Homme\index.php on line 32
```

Hope i exposed the issue clearly, any help and assistance will be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: you havent set up your mysql connection correctly, we need to see your php code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only for the count, mention only the count phrase in the Select clause.

Change :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) product.id,product_name,catname FROM
```

to :

```
SELECT COUNT(product.id)  FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count (pc.cat_ID) FROM productcategory pc inner join category c on c.catid = pc.cat_ID where c.catname = 'sneaker shoes';
```

This will build a temporary table in mysql that joins category and product category but only including results where the catname is sneaker shoes. Then it selects a column to run the count operation on, and returns the result of count.

Comment: @nate0047...i do not understand the shortcut you have used..pc is productcategory? and c is category?

Comment: Exactly. I just aliased the table names so I didn't have to type them out each time.